# Eclipse generates my classes three times in wtpwebapps

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse

i had an issue with PrettyFaces framework that a class is found more than once when using eclipse to run application on server (tomcat 6)

what i found is that eclipse generates the class more than once in wtpwebapps:

```
\WEB-INF\classes\com\myapp\sample\beans\myclass.class
WEB-INF\classes\target\classes\com\myapp\sample\beans\myclass.class
\WEB-INF\classes\target\app-name\WEB-INF\classes\com\myapp\sample\beans\myclass.class
```

**UPDATE:**

i am using **m2eclipse** plugin, and using **maven** as my build tool, maybe there's a configuration wrong with them, or something needed to be configured.

**UPDATE2:**

here's the pom file build, maybe i have something wrong with it:

```
<build>

        <finalName>appName</finalName> 

        <resources>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>

        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5</version>
               <configuration>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

any ideas how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have you installed the "m2e wtp" connector ?   Maven -> Discovery -> Open Catalog  (in Indigo) search "wtp".

Consider using:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

then there may not be any need for setting UTF-8 in the way you do.  But maybe you have another encoding at this point, but then it would be strange to have *.java one encoding and resources in another.  Best to make the whole project same.

Can you confirm if you are building a WAR and this is what you see in the WAR ?  or if are using the launch Tomcat ability from Eclipse and this is what you see in the project.

Also confirm that you have used the Stop Tomcat, Clean, manually check the directory have cleared out (maybe do a workspace refresh, and another Servers -> Clean, manually delete files in Tomcat area).  Then do a Full Publish (to tomcat) and then Start/Debug tomcat to launch.

I would guess if the configuration you now have is as above (and presuming no parent pom.xml is affecting the build do badly) that the files you see are a result of not cleaning the wtpwebapps area after messing around with the maven config.

There are multiple places to check gets cleaned:

```
Temporarly Turn off: Project -> Build Automatically
Stop All Servers instances running like: Tomcat
Run As -> Maven -> clean
Servers -> Clean

Open file browser and validate for yourself outside of Eclipse that the following dirs are empty or non-existant:

  workspaceDirectory/projectDirectory/target   (the maven output folder)

  workspaceDirectory/metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX/wtpwebapps/**
  # This one is ok to have the top level contextPath's, provind they are currently active projects you have added to the server.

  $CATALINA_HOME/

Perform workspace refresh (to ensure Eclipse resync file system state to workspace state).  I do this with clicking on any project in Project Explorer, then Ctrl-Clicking it again to deselect it (so nothing is selected but Project Explorer is in focus) then press F5.   Other people use Ctrl-A to select all projects.

  Now do a Project -> Build All
  Now do a Servers -> Publish  (now check the tree you get)

  Now re-enable Project -> Build Automatically (if you run that way)
```

Comment: i want to confirm that this is what i don't see in my war, and please can you make the answer in form of steps, coz i got lost about what you need me to do, btw i am using helios.

Comment: Step 1) Upgrade to Indigo E3.7 (it is by far the best release of Eclipse yet and I have been using WTP since it started, what you are probably seeing is known issues with Helios E3.6).